# Weird parsing date string error in Android 2.0 emulator

Tags: java, android

I have a simple test code for testing SimpleDateFormat. This code works well on Eclipse and Android 1.5 emulator, but it failed at Android 2.0 emulator. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

```
public class TemplateActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText(R.string.hello);
       setContentView(tv);

       SimpleDateFormat format =
           new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

       String dateStr = "Mon, 17 May 2010 01:45:41 GMT"; 

       try {
           Date parsed = format.parse(dateStr);
           Log.v("Test", parsed.toString());
       } catch (ParseException pe) {
           Log.v("Test", "ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateStr + "\"");
       }

   }
}
```

Log message:

```
V/Test(  400): ERROR: Cannot parse "Mon, 17 May 2010 01:45:41 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1):

In reply to Skrud,

I tried "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", but got the same error message.

I also tried

```
SimpleDateFormat format =
       new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);
```

It works. But the system takes a long time to load time zone names for en_US for each call:

```
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1904ms.
D/dalvikvm(  471): GC freed 10658 objects / 486232 bytes in 88ms
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1400ms.
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1260ms.
D/dalvikvm(  471): GC freed 10615 objects / 491920 bytes in 91ms
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1360ms.
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1232ms.
D/dalvikvm(  471): GC freed 10623 objects / 460544 bytes in 91ms
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1344ms.
I/Resources(  471): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1228ms.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your format string should probably be `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"` instead.

Take a look at the examples on the [SimpleDateFormat's Javadoc page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem too, as i debug problem belong method to convert form Date to string, i have got an solution here:
[Android load timezone too long: Loaded time zone names for en_US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905545/android-load-timezone-too-long-loaded-time-zone-names-for-en-us)

And performance was increase 10 time :)