# Android load timezone too long: Loaded time zone names for en_US

Tags: android, locale

Dear all, i just code a snippet code to get date time string as below:

```
public static String getCurrentDate(){
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Date date = new Date();
    String strDate = date.toString();
    return strDate;
}
```

But problem is it take too long time (about 2 seconds) to convert from Date to string, Logs:

```
10-11 17:52:51.733: INFO/Resources(6835): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 2107ms.
```

Could you please give me a solution how to increase performance of this method

Update for solution:
I just found an solution by tronman at topic:
[How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)
As below:

```
Date date = new Date();
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =
    android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881142/simpledateformat-takes-too-long-when-the-time-zone-is-included

Comment: If you have an answer, why not post it separately and mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to use `SimpleDateFormat` with **default locale**

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.getDefault());
```